# How i can stop the movement of my navigation icon?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I had used navigation slider menu but when i click it's position change it goes slightly in.
How can i stop this movement?
I used this link to code my navigation bar - http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: *"when i click it's position change it goes slightly in"* Unclear, please elaborate.

Comment: It's goes little inside you can see in navigation sliding like in Gmail application or youtuble application we can see it

Comment: Just tried GMail app and I still don't understand what you mean by *"it's goes little inside"*... You mean it bounces? Mine doesn't.

Comment: when i click navigation from which the list are categorizes are open that time its goes inside and when you again dissected it will be again normal